# How to pipe to PHP process using the proc_open() function?

Tags: php, pointers, pipe, stdin

In this case there are two PHP files, *stdin.php* (child process component) and *proc_open.php* (parent process component), both are stored in the same folder of the public_html of a domain. There is also *Program X*, that pipes data into stdin.php.

---

**stdin.php** (this component works)

It is a process that should not be executed throught a browser, because it is destinated to receive input from Program X, and back it all up in a file (named stdin_backup). **This process is working**, because every time Program X pipes input, the process backs it up entirely. If this process is executed with input not passed (such is the case of executing it from a browser), the process creates a file (named stdin_error) with the text "ERROR".

Below, part of the code is ommited because the process works (as mentioned above). The code shown is just to illustrate:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?php
   // Get the input
    $fh_stdin = fopen('php://stdin', 'rb');

    if (is_resource($fh_stdin)) {
        // ... Code that backs up STDIN in a file ...
    } else {
        // ... Code that logs "ERROR" in a file ...
    }
?>
```

---

**proc_open.php** (this component isn't working)

It is a process that must be executed throught a browser, and is destinated to pass input to stdin.php, as Program X does. This process is failing, because every time it is executed, there is no signal of stdin.php being executed: no stdin_error file, no stdin_backup file, not even PHP error_log file.

Code:

```
// Execute a PHP process and pipe input to it
//  - Specify process command
$process_path = __DIR__ . '/stdin.php';
$process_execution_command = 'php ' . $process_path;

//  - Specify process descriptor
$process_descriptor = array(
    0 => array('pipe', 'r') // To child's STDIN
);

//  - Specify pipes container
$pipes = [];

//  - Open process
$process = proc_open($process_execution_command, $process_descriptor, $pipes);

if (is_resource($process)) {
    //  - Send data to the process STDIN
    $process_STDIN = 'Data to be received by the process STDIN';
    fwrite($pipes[0], $process_STDIN);
    fclose($pipes[0]);

    //  - Close process
    $process_termination_status = proc_close($process);
}
```

I am not sure if the command passed to `proc_open()` is correct, because I have not found examples for this case, and as mentioned above, this script is failing. I dont know what else can be incorrect with proc_open.php.

Also when I execute the proc_open.php process, an infinite loop produces, printing the next string over and over:

> X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.20 Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

---

Tryed `popen('php ' . __DIR__ . '/stdin.php', 'w')` instead, and had exaclty the same result: the infinite loop error printing the same string of above, no errors, no logs, and no signals of stdin.php execution.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to open a process and write data into that process' STDIN stream. You can use the [proc_open](http://php.net/proc_open) function for that:

```
$descriptors = array(
    0 => array("pipe", "r"),  // STDIN
    1 => array("pipe", "w"),  // STDOUT
    2 => array("pipe", "w")   // STDERR
);

$proc = proc_open("php script2.php", $descriptors, $pipes);
fwrite($pipes[0], "Your data here...");
fclose($pipes[0]);

$stdout = stream_get_contents($pipes[1]);
$stderr = stream_get_contents($pipes[2]);

fclose($pipes[1]);
fclose($pipes[2]);

$exitCode = proc_close($proc);
```

If you simply want to *test* your 2nd script, It would probably be easier to simply use a shell command:

```
$ echo "your data" | php script2.php
```

Or alternatively,

```
$ php script2.php < datafile.txt
```

**Update, accounting for your edit to the question**

When using the [popen](http://php.net/popen) function, you can either open the process for reading or writing. That allows you to read the process' STDOUT stream or write into the STDIN stream (but not both; if that's a requirement, you'll need to use `proc_open`). If you want to write into the STDIN stream, specify `"w"` as 2nd parameter to `popen` to open the process for writing:

```
$fh_pipe = popen(
    'php script1.php',
    'w'   // <- "w", not "r"!
);

fwrite($fh_pipe, 'EMAIL TEXT') ;
pclose($fh_pipe);
```

Comment: Great answer, upvoted!  Debugging hint: If stdout is empty, check stderr.