# PHP 8.1 on Apache: shell_exec works for shell commands but not other commands

Tags: php, apache

I have Lubuntu 20 running with latest Apache2 and PHP8.1.

I realized using "shell_exec" it only works for commands like "dir" or "echo" or "touch".
But i need to run a command i installed into /usr/local/bin. Calling that one simply makes shell_exec return nothing.

I am also appending "2>&1" at the end of the command, but no luck.

Folders and files are owned by the same user i am running apache with, chown and chmod is fine.
It seems it is blocking such commands, while systems commands are working from PHP.

PHP does not block any of the functions. Any idea why it is failing to run the command?

Update:

### Non-working examples

```
echo shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/sfdx --help 2>&1');
echo shell_exec('/sfdx --help 2>&1');
echo passthru('/usr/local/bin/sfdx --help 2>&1');
```

Running all these on CLI on my Lubuntu works fine even with "php -r" command using the CLI mode of php works. Made a diff of apache php.ini and the cli one, only difference is my display_error and memory_limit setting.

Also tried with popen with no luck, it simply returns nothing.

```
$cmd = "/usr/local/bin/sfdx --help";
$handle = popen($cmd . " 2>&1", 'r');
$read = fread($handle, 2096);
pclose($handle);
```

### Working examples

```
echo shell_exec('dir 2>&1');
echo shell_exec('touch test.log 2>&1');
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample of how you are running it? Are you specifying the full path the executable?

Comment: added some non working examples. my php.ini is the default one but with memory_limit=256m. no disabled functions

Comment: Instead of `echo`, try using `var_dump` to see what kind of "nothing" it really it. Can you confirm error reporting is cranked all the way up on your web version? When you run the commands from the CLI, PHP is run as your user account, however when you run it through the web version, usually a different user is used. I also like to steer people towards [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/proc_open), which, although more verbose, it allows you to inspect `stdout` and `stderr` [independently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024556/231316) which can sometimes help.

Comment: Ok interesting, var_dump shows me "NULL". But i know the command MUST return something, also tried on CLI. So that means something goes wrong, but why "2>&1" does not give me the error? What is missing?

Comment: I honestly only ever use `proc_open`, so I unfortunately can't answer why the redirection stuff doesn't work. According to the docs for `shell_exec`, however, "This function can return `null` both when an error occurs or the program produces no output. It is not possible to detect execution failures using this function. [`exec()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) should be used when access to the program exit code is required. Have you tried that?

Comment: Tried exec() with $output param, but that one only gets an empty Array.

Comment: Have you checked the return value of it?

Comment: exec with output param gives me string(0) "" for the return and array(0) {} for the output param

Comment: Hmm... unfortunately that's the extend of my knowledge for those functions.

Comment: Lot of discussion here but nobody has mentioned checking the read and execute permissions on the path which is the REALLY OBVIOUS cause.

Comment: Folders and files are owned by the same user i am running apache with, chown and chmod is fine. It seems it is blocking such commands, while systems commands are working from PHP. Just to make it clear, a simple "touch test.txt" is working, but any command except those system ones is NOT working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution was to install "sfdx-cli" locally and not globally.

When it is installed globally (npm install -g sfdx-cli) then PHP is for whatever reason not able to run it. No errors returned even when shell_exec returns NULL, which means "error".

After installing it locally and running with "npx sfdx" everything works as expected.